# Svelte not recognizing compiler option 'preprocess'

Tags: typescript, svelte

I am completely new to Svelte and I am setting up a project for the first time. I want to use Svelte with Typescript so I follow the official guide (https://svelte.dev/blog/svelte-and-typescript) and run

```
npx degit sveltejs/template svelte-ts
cd svelte-ts
node scripts/setupTypeScript.js

npm install
```

However right out of the gate when running `npm run dev` or `npm run build` I get this error:

```
bundles src/main.ts → public\build\bundle.js...
[!] (plugin svelte) Error: Unrecognized option 'preprocess'
src\App.svelte
Error: Unrecognized option 'preprocess'
    at C:\Users\teh\svelte-ts\node_modules\svelte\src\compiler\compile\index.ts:40:10
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at validate_options (C:\Users\teh\svelte-ts\node_modules\svelte\src\compiler\compile\index.ts:34:23)
    at compile (C:\Users\teh\svelte-ts\node_modules\svelte\src\compiler\compile\index.ts:75:2)
    at Object.transform (C:\Users\teh\svelte-ts\node_modules\rollup-plugin-svelte\index.js:105:21)
    at C:\Users\teh\svelte-ts\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18734:25
```

When inspecting the `rollup.config.js` file of the Typescript project i noticed that the `preprocess` property is a property of `compilerOptions`:

```
plugins: [
    svelte({
        // enable run-time checks when not in production
        compilerOptions: {
            dev: !production,
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess()
        }
    }),
...
```

but in the none-typescript project (https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess#what-is-it) it is not.

So I moved it just outside the `compilerOptions` and now it seems to build and serve just fin but I have no idea what the ramifications might be down the road.

Am I missing something or is there a bug in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug, [reported here](https://github.com/sveltejs/template/issues/190)
It has been fixed literally minutes after you posted this question though.
So the new template works fine